# src packages exploded eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, structure

This issue has been occurring every now and then and I can not seem to see why or how it is happening
not sure if it is Eclipse or me or a bit of both

In Eclipse, normally I would see a structure like this

Application

---->src

-------->com.xxxxxx.yyyy

------------>activity1

------------>activity2

...

When this happens everything seems to run smoothly in the build or as smoothly as possible for me
however I also see this sometimes and I do not know how to get it back to the prior format

Application

---->src

-------->com

------------>xxxxxx

---------------->yyyy

-------------------->activity1

-------------------->activity2

...

Things tend to blow up very quickly when this happens and I am not able to do things I normally do

Any suggestions??? and what is happening? Is this second version corrupted?

[image: Package explorer view]

[image: The first section in flat mode]

Comment: it's "expanded", not "exploded".

Comment: i have seen it both but i will try to use expanded

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are on the same eclipse view? 
What you are discribing is the general behavior for the Package Explorer and Navigation respectively. They each display the content of your app differently, but it shouldn't matter for the build purposes.

Comment: I added an image to clarify I have both on the same view I will check that now

Comment: added second image to show what the first application looks like in flat

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are switching between different views on eclipse. 
Btw if you want only switch between a flat package navigation (the first you have described), and the hierarchical view you have just to click into View Menu of project explorer (the View menu is the little upside down triangle just under-right the tab Project Explorer),

[image: View menu example]
click on package presentation and switch between flat/hierarchical.

Comment: I wish this was the case but it is not any other ideas. I added a picture of one of the applications in flat and as you can see it is even stranger so all of these are in the heirarchical layout but still expanded

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of your Filter - Settings. I had the same issue, but when configuring the Filter as "Empty packages" , "Empty parent packages" (means the boxes are checked) you will get the usual convience package list as described by you in the "what I usually see" - Section of your image.